# Apache Httpd LogFormat can log "trailer lines"?

Tags: apache, logging, apache2

I have read the documentation for configuring a custom LogFormat for the Apache HTTPD server located here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

In this table these two entries exist:

```
%{VARNAME}^ti   The contents of VARNAME: trailer line(s) in the request sent to the server.
%{VARNAME}^to   The contents of VARNAME: trailer line(s) in the response sent from the server.
```

I've tried to figure out what these two mean and so far I have been unlucky. What do these two mean? What will be logged from the request/response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically possible for certain types of HTTP requests or responses to have a "trailer" -- that is, a header that is included at the end of the message, instead of at the beginning. For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Trailer: Expires

<response content>

Expires: <date>
```

The `%{}^ti` and `%{}^to` log formats can be used to log those trailers.

Not sure what this is for? Don't worry, you're not alone. Most HTTP clients and servers -- including web browsers -- don't support or use trailers. Unless your application specifically uses HTTP trailers, you can safely ignore this.

Comment: Yes! That's the info I was looking for. I now also found the RFC that describes it: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.40

Comment: FYI: I used this to improve this: https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser